# RFC to fetch IDOC linked with Partner Profile/Port/Program ID

Tags: abap, saprfc, idoc

Is there any RFC in which i can pass Partner Profil/Program ID/Port/Logical system name as input and i will get the IDoc types linked with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use **EDI_PARTNER_READ_COMPLETE** RFC.
It will take partner profile as input and will output the inbound & outbound IDocs linked to that.